# NotOLE2FileException was unhandled by user code. Invalid header signature. Cannot import .csv file in my asp.net application

Tags: c#

I have a import functionality in my asp.net application where right now I am able to import only .xls files. I want to make the import functionality working so that it should import .csv file. But I am getting this error[see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTLjA.png)

Can some one please help me in code, how can I import .csv file.

> ImportHandler.cs

```
private IEnumerable<PermanentFlight> ExportPermanentFlightsXlToEf(string fileName)
    {
        Log.Info("Exporting records from Excel to PF Entity starts.");

        HSSFWorkbook workBook;
        using (var file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        }

        var workSheet = workBook.GetSheetAt(0);
        var rowIdx = 1;
        var scheduleName = string.Empty;
        var list = new List<PermanentFlight>();
```